# Entity Framework 4.2 code first in a class library ignoring my connection string

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm building a class library for an application (exitgames photon) and it doesn't have a web.config or an `app.config`.
Therefore I am setting the connection string against the context like this:

```
db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=machinename\\SqlExpress;Initial Catalog=AwesomeDB;Integrated Security=True";
```

The context (db) then ignores the connection string and uses the default one as if I didn't specify it (based on the namespace and context name etc).

Anyone know how to specify the connection string inline thus removing the requirement for an `app.config`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend hard coding the connection string. You can pass the connection string in the default constructor.

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext()
    : base("Data Source=machinename\\SqlExpress;Initial Catalog=AwesomeDB;Integrated Security=True")
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's a class library, then it will use the connection string specified in web.config (web site) or app.config (application) which will use this library.

Comment: why doesn't it use the one from the lib and looks in the main project?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the connection string as a parameter to the constructor of the context.